# Keeping Session data on backend only using JWT

Tags: node.js, session, express, jwt

I'm using JWT on my application and I define my claims like so:

```
const claims = {
   iss: process.env.DOMAIN,
   scope: "game",
   email: user.get("email")
};
```

I verify the token like so:

```
nJwt.verify(socket.handshake.query.token, app.get("jwt.secret"), (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) return;
    console.log(decoded.body.email); // doge@doge.com
});
```

However, it forces me to add session data into `claims` object. Instead, I want to use the token as a session identifier and keep session values on backend only, such as:

```
nJwt.verify(socket.handshake.query.token, app.get("jwt.secret"), (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) return;
    // Since we verified token, read token's session data from backend
});
```

Is there any example about doing this?

Ps. I use Redis so I can SET/GET values via Redis, but I feel like it's bad practice since I'll be developing whole session thing myself.

Comment: Hi use passport library for saving and session with redis store to take care of stuff, for example you can look at https://blog.jscrambler.com/implementing-jwt-using-passport/

Comment: Don't use the whole token as session identifier, there is the jti claim to assign a unique ID to the token which you can save then in your DB to link it to your session data. I also find there is nothing wrong with the redis store, its quite straight forward if you already have it in use.

Comment: @risuch Care to elaborate jti claim? Also, it won't be a session. It will be a handler that reads from Redis. For example, express has req.user that we can rely to obtain session info of the authenticated user. In my case, it will be something like Session.read(identifier, key).then(key => console.log(key)); which is basically a kv storage task.

Comment: @Doge I tried to elaborate a bit more in-depth in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To uniquely identify your token, you could take the whole tokenstring as identifier, though this doesn't make much sense since its too long and unhandy.
Instead, jwt has already standardized a claim for this purpose: **jti**.

So generate your token something like this:

```
var claims = {
   iss: process.env.DOMAIN,
   jti: yourGenerateUniqueIdFunction();
};
```

After JWT verification, you have the jti value.
In the Backend you could model your Session K/V Store like this:

```
[jti].[keyName] -> [value]
```

Accessing K/V something like this:

```
Session.get('3452345.email') //doge@doge.com
```

---

Another way how to achieve what you want is just enabling the default session mechanism in express (https://github.com/expressjs/session), 
then using https://github.com/tj/connect-redis to store the session in your redis store. In this way you could just easily read and write to the req.session and it will be backed to your configured redis store.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply. Second, I have still some issues. The first one is, how can I generate the random JTI in a safe way? Regarding express session and connect-redis, I use both right now. This is my app.js: https://gist.github.com/Aristona/35b7560de98cf43420885b50a89644da Right now, my web application uses passport/connect-redis, where my game (socket.io) relies on JWT. Is it possible to use express-session with socket.io too, so I can do stuff like: `socket.session.name` without having to write a session class myself? If not, if I rely on JWT I must make a Session class right?

Comment: To generate a unique id there are lots of libs already, I personally like this one cause its super simple: https://github.com/dylang/shortid. You can use your already in use express session with socket.io, this library allows you to share your express session with sockets: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session, I think its what you need, but then you dont need jwt anymore.

Comment: I'll have a look at it. What I worry about express-session is the cookies. My game will be hosted on different platforms such as Android (via Cordova), our game website (web) and facebook. The web platform is currently under development and I can combine express session with game client since it is on the same domain. (so I can access cookies on *.mywebsite.com scope) However, do I need additional stuff such as oAuth for mobile clients or can I simply continue using express-session for mobile clients too?

Comment: Without knowing your exact architecture, this should not be an issue. The cookie is set to the domain you are getting it from and on all subsequent requests to that domain it will send it along. I guess all your game clients (Android, Web,..) get the cookie after logging in to the central backend and also continue talking to the same backend during the game.